# Depth buffers and the Z axis

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, 3d, depth-buffer

I am reading an OpenGl book which points out two seemingly contradictory statements:

1. The camera is positioned at the origin and stares down the negative z-axis.
2. The depth buffer clears to a default value of 1.0, and pixels with lower Z values pass the visibility test to appear onscreen.

While I understand the concept of the depth buffer, I do not understand how a Z that is less than another is determined to be "in front" of a *higher* Z value for the purposes of passing the depth buffer test.

I would expect that higher Z values are "in front" and thus win the depth buffer comparison. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is this about desktop OpenGL or OpenGL ES? Because they're not the same thing.

Comment: opengl ES. i thought depth buffering followed the same principles on both versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in the Z-buffer is in range `[0.0,1.0]` and `1.0` is the farther distance that is actually contained in the frustum (anything beyond is not visible).

This means that when drawing a pixel of a shape, if its Z-value is lower than the current one, it is nearer to the eye than what's was there (nothing or just another pixel), so Z is updated and pixel is drawn. Otherwise pixel is discarded.

Comment: ah, so these Z values are not at all the same as the actual z value of the vertex of the shape?

Comment: No, they are normalized: check it out the mathematics here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering#Mathematics

Comment: In OpenGL z-values are in the range [-1,+1] in clip coordinates.

Comment: Yes, and they are then normalized to `[0,+1]` through `z2 = (z1+1)/2` for the purpose of depth test. Because from `[0,+1]` you are able to convert them to a 8/16/24/32 bits integer number to be stored in the Z buffer.

Comment: The points are finally mapped to *device coordinates* by the *viewport transformation* and the z-values will be a fixed point value in the interval [0,1).

Answer (score 1):

After the *model-view transformation* all points are in "view coordinates" where the camera is at the origin looking down the -z axis. The points then pass through the *projection transformation* and are then in "clip coordinates" and here the z-values are mapped to the range [-1,+1]. Points on the *near-plane* will end up with a z-value of -1 and points on the
*far-plane* plane with end up with a z-value of +1.

This is true for all projections. The pipeline expects all coordinate values to be in the range [-1,+1] after clipping and perspective division -- here the points are in *normalized device coordinates.*

Comment: This make sense when depth range `n` and `f` are `0.0` and `1.0` separately, which are their default values.

Comment: @zhy Never set the near plane distance to zero if you are using a perspective projection -- you will effectively have a divide by zero.